# I want to use numberpicker value in another dart file which is an stateful class

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to use my BMI height and weight values which is from an numberpicker , in my another dart file .
This is my HomePage:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  bool isOnePressed = true;
  int num = 0;
  double _currentValue = 10;
  late int _currentValue1 = 100;
  late int _currentValue2 = 30;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BGWidget(
      children: [
        const SizedBox(
          height: 10,
          width: 100,
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 32),
              child: Text(
                'How tall are you?',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Nexa',
                    fontSize: 15,
                    color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5)),
              ),
            ),
            const Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 45,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Text(
              '      How much \n      do you weigh?',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                fontFamily: 'Nexa',
                fontSize: 15,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 0,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 0,
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
              child: SizedBox(
                  width: 80,
                child: NumberPicker(
                  minValue: 100,
                  maxValue: 260,
                  textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 0),
                  selectedTextStyle: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontFamily: 'Athletic',
                      fontSize: 40),
                  value: _currentValue1,
                  onChanged: (value) => setState(() => _currentValue1 = value),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
              child: SizedBox(
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    NumberPicker(
                      minValue: 30,
                      maxValue: 260,
                      textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 0),
                      selectedTextStyle: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontFamily: 'Athletic',
                          fontSize: 40),
                      value: _currentValue2,
                      onChanged: (value) =>
                          setState(() => _currentValue2 = value),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        Material(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
          child: InkWell(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
            onTap: () {
              onBottomButtonPressed();
              setState(() {

              });
            },
            child: Container(
              height: 50,
              width: 300,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                  kButtonCyanColor,
                  kButtonGreenColor,
                ], begin: Alignment.centerLeft, end: Alignment.centerRight),
                boxShadow: const [
                  BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.blueAccent,
                      offset: Offset(0, -0),
                      blurRadius: 10),
                ],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
              ),
              child: const Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Calculate Your BMI',
                  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Nexa', fontSize: 18),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  onButtonPressed(int num) {
    if (num == 1) {
      setState(() {});
      isOnePressed = true;
    } else {
      setState(() {});
      isOnePressed = false;
    }
  }


  onBottomButtonPressed() {
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => ResultScreen(),
        ));
  }

}
```

And this is my result page :

```
class ResultScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ResultScreen({super.key});


  @override
  State<ResultScreen> createState() => _ResultScreenState();
}


class _ResultScreenState extends State<ResultScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: BGWidget(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(
            height: 200,
          ),
          const Center(
            child: Text(
              'Your BMI is ',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white, fontFamily: 'Nexa', fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ),
          Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [Image.asset('assets/images/iconn.png')],
          ),
         ],
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

I want to calculate BMI in result page and use it in a text widget.
Is it possible as all?

I posted a question about doing this but i didn't ask it with more details.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass data to `ResultScreen` when navigating to it. In order to do this you need to define what variables do you need inside `ResultScreen`.

```
class ResultScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ResultScreen({super.key, required this.height, required this.weight});
  final double height;
  final double weight;

  double get _bmi => weight / (height * height);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Text('$_bmi'));
  }
}
```

Passing data:

```
 onBottomButtonPressed() {
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => ResultScreen(
          height: _someHeight,
          weight: _weight),
        ));
  }
```

Make sure to checkout [Flutter Cookbook](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/passing-data) for solutions to common problems while writing Flutter apps.

Comment: I want to calculate BMI with 194 cm height , and 71 kg weight.
It's showing it like that :
your bmi is : 0.0018864 .....

Comment: you need to convert cm to m first before you calculate
194cm -> 1.94m

Comment: I appreciate a lot . You saved my project ❤️